# User Not Visible in AD Users and Computer

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have a user that shows up in using the PowerShell Get-ADUser command, but when I go into AD Users and Computers the user isn't visible. I am thinking it has something to do with the $ at the end of the name, but I am new to all of this and just got asked to try and figure who/what the user is on our system. Below are the results from the PS command (I changed the actual username returned from the query):

```
DistinguishedName    : CN=Username$,CN=Users,DC=ourdomain,DC=org  
EmailAddress         :   
Enabled              : True  
GivenName            :   
Name                 : Username$  
ObjectClass          : user  
ObjectGUID           : e5dd0482-dac9-4f93-bc17-03d5f970943d  
PasswordExpired      : False  
PasswordLastSet      : 9/8/2015 5:49:15 PM  
PasswordNeverExpires : False  
SamAccountName       : Username$  
SID                  : S-1-5-21-2129867641-1687574238-1546849883-9191  
Surname              : 
UserPrincipalName    :
```

Any thoughts on this user?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you search AD for "username$" (or whatever the actual username is)? One thing we don't have here for certain is the *displayName*, which is not necessarily the same as the CN or the name, but is what you see in the ADUC list. If the CN is "username$" but the displayName is "Bob", then you might be seeing "Bob" in ADUC and not realizing that's the same object.

Comment: You can run `Get-ADUser -identity username$ -Properties displayName` to get the displayName (it will be the first row in the output). That will be what to look for in the Users container in ADUC.

Comment: The DisplayName is coming back blank

Comment: It appears I'm wrong about displayName being what is shown in AD. It's some other property. I can't make displayName blank but I can make it whitespace so nothing shows up. It's possible you don't have the right permissions on the object and therefore ADUC won't show it to you. Can you see it in ADSIEdit? You could run dsacls in powershell to find the security settings on the user: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/03/12/use-powershell-to-explore-active-directory-security.aspx

Comment: Good idea, forgot about that tool. Yes it shows up there, looks like it was trust account that was setup by someone.

Answer (score 5):

I don't agree with the given answer.

You are allowed to create user accounts that end in the dollar sign ($) character, and Active Directory can still tell the difference between that user account and a computer account, because the object still has `user` as its `ObjectClass`.

I just created a user with a trailing dollar sign in the name, and there were no issues viewing the user account in ADUC, or Powershell, or the ADUC search dialog. The account was just fine.

So your problem lies elsewhere.

So my theory is that someone has changed the `showInAdvancedViewOnly` attribute on that user account to `TRUE`, and this will hide the user account from the ADUC console's view, unless you were to check "View -> Advanced Features" from the menu.

Not 100% certain, but that's my bet.

Edit: It's also worth noting that creating a user account with a trailing dollar sign, while technically legal, is not something that you just "accidentally" do. For instance, ADUC would not allow me to do it. It just silently stripped the dollar sign. However, using more advanced methods, I was able to get the dollar sign onto the end of the CN of the username. So all things considered, this sounds a little fishy, like someone trying to hide a user account.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. I was pretty sure I already had that option on and just confirmed it is on. So must be something else causing it not to be visible.

Comment: Well then we still have a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an account that gets created when you have an AD trust setup.  You should be able to see it in ADSIEDIT.  Look at the extended properties for sAMAccountType (TRUST_ACCOUNT).  The account name will match the domain name that the trust is setup with.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The $ means that AD is interpreting the user as a computer.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. Still doesn't explain why I don't see/find it in AD Users and Computers

Comment: Try searching for it without the $ as a Computer.

Comment: I tried that, and just tried again to verify. Nothing is found searching for it as a computer without the $ sign.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue and wanted to post my response for anyone checking this in the future.

There was an account that was found using Get-ADUser that was not visible in ADUC or Admin Center. It also has a "$" appended on the account. I did the same tests as previously stated, created a test user with trailing "$". I had no issues creating or viewing.

I then did a search for the name without the "$". It appears there was a previous inbound trusted domain set up with that name. I then used ADSIEdit and was able to find the user object with the correct name. Then checked the sAMAccount type and confirmed it was a (TRUST_ACCOUNT).

Still not sure why I can't view it in ADUC or Admin Center (I have advanced features on), but at least know its purpose now.